# Replace values in raster 1 with values from raster 2 in ArcMap 10.7.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

Raster 1 is a DEM of a study site.
Raster 2 is a smaller DEM of the corrected water depth of a river that runs through the site.

How do I replace the pixels within raster 1 with the corrected water depth pixels (raster 2)

They are both of the same resolution (0.2m)

Comment: You should research the `Con` function.

Comment: In addition to being the same resolution, you'll need to confirm that the two rasters are snapped to each other.

Comment: great - thank you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Mosaic to New Raster" tool in ArcMap.  (Don't confuse this with creating a Mosaic raster dataset, which is a different thing.)  This tool creates a new single raster by merging multiple rasters.

In the tool, you can configure which rasters take precedence in areas where they overlap.  In this case, you would want your water depth raster to take precedence.  Specify this in the "Mosaic Operator" parameter.